# How do I use eloquent for TIMEDIFF?

Tags: php, laravel, time, timestamp, eloquent

```
public function fire()
{       
    Log::info('Delete abandoned builds.');

    $builds = Build::where('status', Build::STATUS_ABANDONED)
                    ->whereRaw (TIMEDIFF(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s'), created_at) >= '01:00:00')->get();
                        $buildRepository->delete($build);
    $buildRepository = new BuildRepository();

}
```

Basically, I have to delete builds after they have been abandoned for 1 hour. It gives me an error as TIMEDIFF is undefined. Can someone tell me how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Eloquent and `DateTime` instead of `TIMEDIFF`

```
$date = new DateTime;
$date->modify('-60 minutes');
$formatted_date = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

DB::table('builds')
  ->where('status', Build::STATUS_ABANDONED)
  ->where('created_at','>=',$formatted_date)
  ->delete();
```